# SQL Command "Enter Parameter Value" With ComboBox Data

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I currently have the following code

```
Private Sub dbSearch_Click()

Dim ManfactQuery As String
Dim ModelQuery As String
Dim strSQL As String

ManfactQuery = Me.cboManfact.Column(1)
ModelQuery = Me.cboModel.Column(1)

If ManfactQuery = Null Or ManfactQuery = Null Then
strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ModelSolution = " & ModelQuery & ""

    Else

        If ModelQuery = Null Or ModelQuery = "" Then
    strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ManufacturerSolution = " & ManfactQuery & ""

    Else

        strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ManufacturerSolution = " & ManfactQuery & " AND   [Solutions].ModelSolution = " & ModelQuery & ""
    End If

End If

Me.lstSolution.RowSource = strSQL

End Sub
```

Im trying to pass the text values of the combobox into the SQL statement and it works to and extent, but i get "Enter Parameter value" popup dialog box. If i then input the value of the comboboxes and click ok, it populates the listbox with the appropriate field, but I need to not have the dialog box if possible.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you read this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303134?

Comment: I have read through it, but i personally couldn't get it to work. I'm probably being stupid though? :( I am using Access 2013 if that makes any difference

Comment: OK - did you get stuck on a step? Did you get an error? This sounds like an MS bug not a coding issue. In other words - I can't give you any code to fix the problem.

Comment: I didnt get an error, but it just brought up a bunch of data from the form itself. The problem is, this isnt a query, its just hard coded into the button "db_search" So i dont think the SQL command is reading the value passed from ManfactQuery or ModelQuery properly. The comboBoxes pull data from another 2 tables and then the db search references a third

Comment: Could it be the fact that i am using the .Column(1) on the combobox instead of value. Im only interested in the text contained in the combobox is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you probably mean this:

`If ManfactQuery = Null Or ManfactQuery = Null Then`

to be this:

`If ManfactQuery = Null Or ManfactQuery = "" Then`

and it can be better represented like this:

`If Nz(ManfactQuery)="" then`

Now to the actual issue. Since `ManfactQuery` and `ModelQuery` are text values they need to be surrounded by single quotes in your SQL text like this:

`strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ModelSolution = '" & ModelQuery & "'"`

Comment: THANK YOU! Ill get right on it, and report back shortly

Comment: Adjusted accordingly, however when i now click the button, the parameter value dialog box doesnt show up, but i do not get anything appear in the lsitbox, unlike manually entering the values into the dialog box

Comment: You may have an additional issue here:


`ManfactQuery = Me.cboManfact.Column(1)
ModelQuery = Me.cboModel.Column(1)`


try setting Column(1) (or whichever column has the actual values you are looking for) to be the bound column and use


`ManfactQuery = Me.cboManfact
ModelQuery = Me.cboModel`

Then verify you are getting the proper values by `MsgBox(ManfactQuery)`

Comment: all solved now Knight, thank you so much. Youve fixed my problem perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED IT. Thank you so much @Charlie and @SunKnight0

Code is as follows:

```
Private Sub dbSearch_Click()

Dim ManfactQuery As String
Dim ModelQuery As String
Dim strSQL As String

ManfactQuery = Me.cboManfact.Column(1)
ModelQuery = Me.cboModel.Column(1)

If Len(ModelQuery) = 0 Then

strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ModelSolution = '" & ModelQuery & "'"

    Else

If Len(ManfactQuery) = 0 Then

strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ManufacturerSolution = '" & ManfactQuery & "'"

    Else

strSQL = "SELECT [Solutions].SolutionText FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].ManufacturerSolution = '" & ManfactQuery & "' AND [Solutions].ModelSolution = '" & ModelQuery & "'"

    End If

End If

Me.lstSolution.RowSource = strSQL

End Sub
```

Thank you all so much, after 3 days of trying to figure this out, ive got it!

Comment: Thank you, i shall ammend this :)